# Laravel, how to pass object through redirect() route()?

Tags: php, laravel

My goal is to pass object from current function to other function. As you can see the codes below, I have provided a multiple `return` approach I've done in the controller section. I have commented each of its error. I am not sure why that is happened although some of the approaches are from the voted answer in some other questions.

**Array Content [ dump($data = $request->all()); ]**

[image]

**Controller**

```
public function supply_status(Request $request, $data)
{
    dump($data);
}

public function supply_redirect(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    //option 1
    return redirect()->route('supply_status', compact('data')); // "Array to string conversion" error

    //option 2
    return redirect()->route('supply_status', ['data' => $data]); // "Array to string conversion" error

    //option 3
    return redirect()->route('supply_status')->with('data', $data); // Missing required parameters for [Route: supply_status] [URI: supply_status/{data}].

    //option 4
    return redirect()->action('TestController@supply_status')->with('data', $data); // Missing required parameters for [Route: supply_status] [URI: supply_status/{data}].
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('supply_status/{data}', 'TestController@supply_status')->name('supply_status');
```

Comment: You can't pass an array as a route parameter, how would you expect the URL to work?

Comment: If you need a route parameter in a redirect, you can always do `redirect("/supply-status/".$param);`; but yeah, **won't work with an array.**

Comment: @TimLewis i got `Array to string conversion`

Comment: @Devon is there other alternatives?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, seems like an XY problem, since we don't know what you're trying to achieve.  You can certainly flash the $data to the session like you are with option 3, but you wouldn't need a route parameter for that.

Comment: Are you sure you want everything in `$data` to be route params? That would be the same as `/$data[0]/$data[1]/$data[2] ...`, and your route would have to handle that, like `Route::get("/supply-data/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}", ...);` Maybe these should be query string parameters?

Comment: @TimLewis thats was my last resort...can this code be a little bit simplified? just asking

Comment: @Devon so i just have to erase the `{data}` param at my routes?

Comment: Unless you have some reason for it?  If you're expecting an array there, that won't work.  You can't have a URL of `supply_status/<array here>`, that just wouldn't make sense

Comment: Is your `$data` array going to be constant? Cause you could do `/supply-status/{id}/{paid}/{paid_at}/{signature}`, then `redirect("/supply-status/".$data["id"]."/".$data["paid"]/ ...";` but that's messy, and prone to break. Putting it into `session()`, using `redirect()->with(["data" => $data]);` will make it accessible with `session()->get("data")["id"];` in `TestController`, so maybe look into that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this situation you really should use the [Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session) class

```
Session::put('customer_data', $request->all());
Session::save();
redirect()->route('foobar');
```

in foobar

```
if($data = Session::get('customer_data')) {
   dump($data);
}
```

You could alternatively also do: `redirect()->with(['customer_data' => $request->all()])` and then fetch it the same way with `Session::get('customer_data')` or `session()->get('customer_data')`

Answer (score -5):

You can use the PHP function **serialize** and put the result in a GET or POST parameter:
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.serialize.php

Then you have to **unserialize** your data : 
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.unserialize.php

But this will not be safe as the user can modify that data. You should persist its on session or something else, depending of your needs to do this operation.

return redirect()->route('supply_status', ['data' => serialize($data)]);

dump(unserialize($data));